# In what order are the aggregated classes deleted?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a basic class A that aggregate B and C:

```
class A  
{  
    B _b;  
    C _c;  
}
```

in what order are _b and _c going to be deleted?
I've read somewhere that it's the reverse order of their allocation.
So I guess in this little example _c is deleted before _b, right?

Now if I have a A constructor that looks like that:

```
A::A():  
_c(...),  
_b(...)  
{  
}
```

In what order are _b and _c's constructors called?
If _b's constructor is indeed called before _c's one (regarding their order in A), then I find it really counter intuitive!

In this case what will be the order of destruction?

Thanks for your help ! :)

(On a side note I seem totally unable to type '}' into Stackoverflow's editor. Had to copy and paste from an external editor !?)

Comment: If you need to know, you're probably doing something wrong...

Comment: Also note: A good compiler will warn you about the initializer list order telling you that b will be constructed first. And if you set the compiler to treat all warnings as errors (which is a good idea) then the code will not compile if the initializer list is in the wrong order.

Comment: @mmyers What makes you think I may doing something wrong?

Actually my code was crashing because _b is currently pointing _c and needs _c to help clean some other objects. So _c must be deleted after _b. Is that bad?

Comment: @julio Well the fact that C and B depend on each other and that A is using them both points to the fact that your could could use some refactoring (probably).

Comment: I can think of good reasons it might matter. Suppose _b is a stream (constructed using params of A's constructor), and _c is a stream wrapper. It takes a reference to a stream as a constructor parameter, and changes the character encoding of everything written to it before writing to the wrapped stream. Since A constructs both _b and _c (in that order), there is no reason at all that _c shouldn't depend on _b in some way. _c's destructor may well write some buffered bytes to _b. The only "refactor" needed would be to make sure they're con-/destructed in the right order.

Comment: ... so, the initialiser list would be `_b(some_params), _c(_b)`, and I've just realised that I gave my example the other way around from the one in the question, where actually _b is dependent on _c. Anyway yswim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are destroyed (not deleted) in the reverse order that they were created.  It is this that also requires that regardless of how the constructor is written that all the members must be constructed in a consistent order.  If each constructor could define the order that the members were constructed, each class instance would have to carry around information on how it was constructed, in order to be able to destruct in reverse order.  By defining the order to always be the order that the members were declared in the class definition, the order of construction does not change from constructor to constructor.

In your example, first, memory is allocated for the full A class.  Next `_b` is constructed, then `_c` then `A`.  If A were to have a base class, that would be fully constructed before any of the above.  On deletion, the reverse occurs.  First `A`'s destructor is called, then `_c` is destructed, then `_b` (then any base classes are destructed).  Finally the memory for 'A' is freed.

Comment: Ok so do you mean that in my constructor example, _b's constructor is called before _c's ?

Comment: Yes, in your example _b's constructor is called first.

Comment: Good to mention the rationale behind the construction order!  +1

Answer (score 7):

Non-static class members are always destroyed in the reverse order that they were constructed.

The order that members are constructed always matches the order that they are declared in the class definition. The order that members appear in a constructor's initalizer list has no effect on the order of their construction.

In your example `_c` is destroyed, then `_b` is destroyed, the reverse order of their declaration in the class.

Comment: Agreed. I would emphasize a bit more the fact the the order of declaration - and not the order in the initialization list - defines the order of construction.

Comment: And I wish that C++ required that items in initializer lists be given in the initialization order.  It would be a minor pain, but I think it would eliminate this irritating point of confusion. At the very least, I wish my tools would give me a refactoring command to do this (hell, even a compiler warning - can I get that from MSVC or GCC with some option?)

Comment: GCC does warn about this with `-Wall`, but I'm not sure if there's a specific warning to turn this on.

Answer (score 0):

class members constructors are always called in the order of their declaration, regardless the call order in the master class constructor.

in your case,

```
A::A():  
_c(...),  
_b(...)  
{  
}
```

implies the same construction/destruction order than

```
A::A():  
_b(...),
_c(...)  
{  
}
```